# My Batch file wont continue while windows is locked

Tags: batch-file, vbscript, lockscreen

I have a batch file which calls other programs to open and run.

I want this batch file to run overnight while my computer is locked. I use Windows Task Scheduler to run this program overnight. The batch file runs fine except when it gets to `start Check1.msl`.  Then windows can't seem to find that file.  When I unlock my computer and manually execute the batch file, it has no problem finding and running those files.

Here is my code:

```
@echo off
Start Check1.msl

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
start passwordinjector.vbs

IF EXIST C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\check.rpt (

    taskkill /IM MAINRDW.exe >nul

    PING 1.1.1.1 -w 500 -n 1
    Start Trial.msl

    PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
    start passwordinjector.vbs

    Del C:\Users\Username\Desktop\New folder\check.rpt

) ELSE (
    PING 1.1.1.1 -w 500 -n 1
    taskkill /IM MAINRDW.exe >nul
)
```

**EDIT:**

I've been trying it out for awhile now. To test it, I simply use Windows Task Scheduler to run it a minute out then lock my computer and wait for the Scheduler to kick in.

Here is what I have so far:

```
@echo off
cd /d "%~dp0"

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 2000 -n 1
echo starting the check1 msl file
Start Check1.msl

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 2000 -n 1
echo starting the password injector file
WScript //B passwordinjector.vbs

IF EXIST C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\New folder\check.rpt (
echo check if the check exists
taskkill /IM MAINRDW.exe /f >nul 2>&1


PING 1.1.1.1 -w 2000 -n 1
echo It does exist, so run the next Trial msl
Start Trial.msl

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 3000 -n 1
WScript //B passwordinjector.vbs

Del C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\New folder\check.rpt


) ELSE (
PING 1.1.1.1 -w 1000 -n 1
it doesnt exits
taskkill /IM MAINRDW.exe /f >nul 2>&1

)
exit
```

It is very hard to troubleshoot batch files. If anyone has any suggestions, I would appreciate it. Through trial and error, I figured out (still not sure) that it wasn't executing the .vbs script. So I looked it up online from [Microsoft's developer network](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xazzc41b(v=vs.85).aspx) and got the syntax `WScript //B`.

**EDIT2:**

I put a `pause` into the code to break it down and make sure it is doing what it is supposed to do. Its not.

The `Check1.msl` will spit out a file named `check.rpt`. When i run it manually and the batch file pauses - `check.rpt` is there.  I schedule the task and lock my computer. When I log back in, the msl program is open and the cmd prompt is sitting at pause but there is NO `check.rpt` file.

Here is what I have at the beginning:

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD "%~dp0

ECHO CD is now %CD%

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 2000 -n 1
echo starting the check1 msl file
DIR Check1.msl
Start Check1.msl

PING 1.1.1.1 -w 2000 -n 1
echo starting the password injector file
WScript //B passwordinjector.vbs

pause
```

I've tried `cscript passwordinjector.vbs` to no avail.

Comment: set your working directory. A batch started with Task Scheduler has another "homedir"

Comment: I'd also check your power options and make sure the hard disk isn't shut off when in stand by.

Comment: Does the `IF EXIST` look right?  Not sure if I got that right.  With the research I've done I can't figure out if that's OK.

Comment: To troubleshoot batch files: `echo ON`. And use `TIMEOUT` instead of pinging a public IP...

Comment: `if exist "C:\Users\USERNAME\Desktop\New folder\check.rpt"` note double quotes surrounding a file specification as it contains a blank space character....

Comment: If you can get away with it, you can download an AutoIT script - there are a couple floating around called: NoSleep.exe that will move your mouse one pixel right, one pixel left.  This is not a regular recommended practice in a Domain, but will keep your computer from locking (sleeping).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue lies in the VBScript.  I use `.sendkey` to inject the password. This is retricted while the computer is locked; so I'm out of luck.

Comment: Something about this bugs me.  Why are you sending a password in a batch/VB script?  You are setting yourself up for a fail in a security Audit!!  If you need to run a task across the domain, you need to either schedule the task on the destination machine or run it remotely.  We can't even run PSEXEC anymore.  It is considered a "Hacker tool" even though engineered and built by a "Microsoft Fellow" - formerly SysInternals.

Answer (score 0):

The .bat script can make the current working directory to be the one in which it is located by:

```
PUSHD "%~dp0"
```

Remember to POPD before exiting.

```
@ECHO OFF
PUSHD "%~dp0"

ECHO CD is now %CD%
DIR Check1.msl

START Check1.msl
...
```

Comment: or you can just use `cd /d "%~dp0"` and not worry about `popd` just another option.

Comment: I made some edits - I tried your `cd /d "%~dp0"` as well as directly cd like `cd /d "C:\Users\Username\Desktop\NewFolder".  Neither seemed to work.